# Attach chart.js image to JetBrains Space POST request

Tags: javascript, chart.js, jetbrains-space

I'm struggling to find any resources for creating an issue in [JetBrain's Space docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/api.html#api-playground).

This is what I'm working with, mostly from their API playground:

```js
function createIssue(apiData) {
        const { url, auth, title, description, assignee, status, imageData, customFields } = apiData;
        window.fetch(`${url}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`,
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: `${title}`,
                description: `${description}`,
                assignee: `${assignee}`,
                status: `${status}`,
                attachments: [
                    // image data here?
                ],
                    customFields: [
                {
                    fieldId: `${customFields[0].fieldId}`,
                    value: {
                        className: `${customFields[0].value.className}`,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),
    });
}
```

`api.imageData` is currently being initialized with [`.toBase68Image('image/png', 1)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#tobase64image-type-quality)

Given that this a data url, how can I include this in my request as an *attachment*? Or is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and there is a better approach to take?